# Cannot select column when the type is set as "xml"

Tags: php, sql-server

I can select any other column, but if I try "SELECT *" or attempt to select the column (set as xml) specifically the result returns nothing, I am running PHP 5.4 and Microsoft SQL 2008R2.

If I select using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it works fine.

Example of Code: (Returns `$nservers = 1`) // Not the XML Column

```
$qservers = "SELECT SourceIP FROM ARRC.dbo.tblLicenseActivation WHERE AssetID = '1000432'";
$rservers = mssql_query($qservers);
$nservers = mssql_num_rows($rservers);
```

Example of Code: (Returns `$nservers = 0`)  // Everything

```
$qservers = "SELECT * FROM ARRC.dbo.tblLicenseActivation WHERE AssetID = '1000432'";
$rservers = mssql_query($qservers);
$nservers = mssql_num_rows($rservers);
```

Example of Code: (Returns `$nservers = 0`) // XML Column

```
$qservers = "SELECT ActivationPayload FROM ARRC.dbo.tblLicenseActivation WHERE AssetID = '1000432'";
$rservers = mssql_query($qservers);
$nservers = mssql_num_rows($rservers);
```

Example of Code: (Returns `$nservers = 0`) // XML + Non XML Column

```
$qservers = "SELECT SourceIP, ActivationPayload FROM ARRC.dbo.tblLicenseActivation WHERE AssetID = '1000432'";
$rservers = mssql_query($qservers);
$nservers = mssql_num_rows($rservers);
```

Comment: Show an example of your table and the code calling the select

Comment: The column type is actually set to xml, not that just XML data exists in the column.

Comment: Try using the functions from the [sqlsrv extension][1] instead. The mssql extension relies on a very old client library. IIRC, it doesn't handle XML columns.


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php

Comment: I should have clarified that the PHP installation is running on CENTOS6 / Apache. It looks like the sqlsrv is for php installations on Windows. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to the underlying problem, but as a workaround, you could try converting the XML to a string in SQL:

```
$qservers = "SELECT SourceIP, CONVERT(varchar(max),ActivationPayload) FROM ARRC.dbo.tblLicenseActivation WHERE AssetID = '1000432'";
$rservers = mssql_query($qservers);
$nservers = mssql_num_rows($rservers);
```